# How to rehash files

Tags: hashing

I downloaded a game from torrent (via my android phone) For My windows 8 (32 bit) pc

After Downloading I Needed To Intall The Game

But In Steps To run The Game it is said to

---

Installation:
1.Rehash files before install
2.Disable Anti-Virus before installation
3.Open Setup.exe
4.Follow Instructions
5.Install additional softwares
6.Install Game
7.Play the game using the desktop shortcut

---

I dont Know what Is Rehashing And How It Is done?

Do I Need To Download It again??????

Comment: @Ramhound He was downloading it for the Windows PC.

Comment: @Ramhound **For** the W8 PC. I.e. the OP wants to install and run the exe on the PC. Rohit, why is the phone involved?

Comment: **I have no idea.** Confusing question. The part about the phone is irrelevant to the task at hand.

Answer (score 4):

All it is saying by "rehash files" is asking you to hash what you downloaded to ensure it lines up with the hash that was provided at the download site. This is a means of checking the integrity of the file and making sure you haven't downloaded any additional files by accident.

Go to where you downloaded it, find out what type of hash it has (MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256) and then download a free program to perform the hash of what you downloaded and see if it matches.

A hash is a one way function that essentially uses a complex algorithm to generate a unique identifier for any input (file, text, etc.)

NOTE: You should be very careful about installing software that asks you to disable antivirus before installing, especially if it comes from an untrusted source....

Comment: That was my guess too, but why "rehash".

Comment: Yeah, the "re" is unnecessary, they just mean "hash" I am assuming.

Comment: Also, lots of antivirus is paranoid, so switching it off can be a good idea. What matters is just the source.

Comment: I disagree with GKFX. Disabling antivirus is almost certainly a terrible idea. Even trusted sources get hacked.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - Agreed. A better approach would be to attempt the install, and if it gets blocked by Antivirus, add an exception if you REALLY want to run what was blocked. But I would find the file that was blocked and run the hash against VirusTotal first to avoid letting trojans run free on your system.

Comment: @Ramhound I think you need to re-read the initial question. He torrented the file VIA his android device to be used on a WINDOWS device. Please read the questions fully before making statements that other people's answers are unhelpful.

Comment: @Chris Surely checking for signatures on the installer is more important? Antivirus can easily give false positives/negatives, and anyone bright enough to hack a site will make the virus not be picked up. It's hard for antivirus to work out what's malicious when file handling and internet – all Cryptolocker needs – are used by safe programs too.

Comment: That said, maybe it's not a good idea to disable AV, but it's not very suspicious. Maybe AV is known to dislike the program or something.

Comment: No, what is meant here is to rehash using BitTorrent hash tree. uTorrent can do it.

Answer (score 1):

The BitTorrent in by itself has hashes: that is how it checks for validity of pieces of files. You can use uTorrent to rehash: press stop in right click menu and then press rehash.